# Microservice aggragate design?

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

I develop an eCommerce app with DDD as a microservice.

I have product service, category service, price service.

First question:

I don't store any info about category or price in product service because they are in their own service.

Should I store default value or etc in the product model?

second question:

When CreateProductRequest comes to product service. It includes category and price data in the request model. After creating a product. I fire productCreatedEvent. It stores created product id, category, price info.

Other services consume that event and save its own database related data. For example, pricing service saves price with product id, price. Category service saves product id and category id.

Should I send all data in one event like productCreatedEvent? Or send separated commands like createProductCategory to category service and createProductPrice to price service via rabbitMQ or grpc call.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should think if it makes sense to separate product service from price and category services. I dont know what are the responsibilities of each one, but only makes sense to split them if each one has functionality on its own.
I mean, if it is impossible to have a price or a category without its product, the three would be part of the same microservice. There will be a product service wich contains products each of one with its price and category.

In case that this division makes sense because the price and category service have its own functionality and responsibilities independent from the product, these are the answers in my opinion

The first question should be to create categories and prices in first place and when you need to create a product you will reference the price id and category id and pass it to the producto service.

regarding the second question, You should not send price and category info to the product because these are not info that product service have to know, so the proper way to do, as I said before, is first create the price and category calling its own services and then send the createProduct command with the reference.

But once more, I think the best approach is to merge these three services into one because they seem very related

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think other services need only productId. Product means id for category service . Category service has categories and attributes . Pricing has discounts. They need to be seperated services. You suggest to create first category and pricing service info then save product with referances. My opinion was creating product first. Then save other service datas with saved productId. I neet to merge them in search service as denormalize for facet search